# HTTP Response Code while updating record in DB

Tags: api, http-response-codes

I have an API interacting with Database. In case of an Update request an ID and Data is received to update the Row in DB. In case the ID is not present in Database a message '0 rows updated' is returned with success response from DB. What should be the HTTP Response Code returned from API. I do not think 404 is apt in this scenario. Please suggest!!

Comment: you can return http 304 Not Modified I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You could first make a call to database and check whether ID exists or not. If it doesn't exists then do the following:-

```
if (Id <= 0)
            return ServiceResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, null, new List<string> { "Invalid Id"});
```

Comment: Will it be a BAD request http 400? The request is not malformed. it is a data issue. I could do the same in case of error '0 rows updated' as well. Could you please explain more why HTTP 400 will be suited for this.